# Losing variable scope in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This works as it should

```
set "status="
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %%H in (`schtasks.exe /fo csv /query /tn "\MS2\Import Process"`) do set "status=%%H"
set status=%status:"=%
echo The Import status: %status%
```

This says the status is `READY`

I wanted to check the status every 5 seconds for 1 minute:

```
for /l %%i in (1, 5, 300) do (
    set "status="
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %%H in (`schtasks.exe /fo csv /query /tn "\MS2\Import Process"`) do set "status=%%H"
    set status=%status:"=%
    echo The Import status: %status%
    timeout /t 5
)
```

This says the status is always empty

I am using %% notion because I run it in a batch file.

Why doesnt status get set properly in the for loop

Edit: Attempt with delayedexpansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%i in (1, 5, 300) do (
    set "status="
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %%H in (`schtasks.exe /fo csv /query /tn "\MS2\Import Process"`) do set "status=%%H"
    echo The Import status: !status!
    timeout /t 5
)
```

It still just says status is empty. 
I also get `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.` just before the echo

I tried putting `set "status="` outside the for loop with no avail.

Comment: ...the famous delayed expansion trap -- see [this site](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (there is a great example with a `for /L` loop)...

Comment: Not having much luck using it, I don't know if `%%H` becomes `!!H` the whole thing is confusing.

Comment: Keep `%%H`. Change `%status%` to `!status!` and `%status:"=%` to `!status:"=!` etc.

Comment: That is what I originally thought but it says the status is now `"=` rather than `READY`. if I remove the `set status=!status:"=!` I just get a blank status just like before

Comment: Before you actually use `delayed expansion` (that is `!status!`), you need to enable it by placing `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script, because it is disabled as per default...

Comment: Yeah, I added `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. Ill update attempt in question

Comment: [Remove surrounding `"` double quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) using `%%~H` and skip trailing blank line taken from `schtasks` output using `if not defined status set "status=%%~H"`.

Comment: Please post as an answer because I am getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove "surrounding double quotes" using `%%~H` and
- skip trailing blank line taken from `schtasks` output using `if not defined status …`
- **Edit**: [Windows stores scheduled tasks as XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454183/3439404). To avoid (a bit confusing) message `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified` check the task existence (test `errorlevel` from filesystem).

Updated code snippet:

```
echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "tasktocheck=\MS2\Import Process"

rem check scheduled task existence silently
>NUL 2>&1 schtasks.exe /fo csv /query /tn "%tasktocheck%"
if errorlevel 1 (
     echo "%tasktocheck%" scheduled task not found
     rem quit the script raising errorlevel 1
     exit /B 1
)
for /l %%i in (1, 5, 300) do (
    rem remove variable `status` (i.e. make it undefined) in next line
    set "status="
    for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %%H in (
            `schtasks.exe /fo csv /query /tn "%tasktocheck%"`
        ) do if not defined status set "status=%%~H"
    rem      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  skip trailing blank line taken from schtasks output
    rem Remove "surrounding double quotes"       ^  note the ~ tilde
    echo The Import status: !status!
    timeout /t 5
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%%~H` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Ok that is what I thought you meant for the most part. I am getting 

`ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.`
`The Import status:`

every time the loop runs. So still the same issues

Comment: @LearningJrDev answer updated. That `The system cannot find the file specified` is a bit confusing message isn't it?